# Finding edges that are symmetric in a directed graph

Tags: caching, graph

I have a graph representing one-way friendships, stored as a set of edges (A knows B). I can't seem to find a good, cache-efficient way to get the set of all "A knows B and B knows A". Does anyone have an algorithm that would be able to solve that?

Language : C (although more interested in an algorithm than a solution)
Dataset size : about 1200000 edges
Data structure : the edges are stored so that all the edges that start from A are adjacent
Things I tried : doing the naïve version (going through the data, and for each A knows B, go look if B knows A). Obviously, the random accesses make this quite a bit slow.

Comment: Please post whatever you have tried till now and then ask people to suggest improvements.

Comment: What language? Data structure? How large is the data set?